# Are this functions a probability measure?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I´m kind of lost with these statistics exercises. I need to prove is this functions are  probability measure. To be a probability measure on $\Omega $it has to satisfy the conditions:

1. $P(\Omega) = 1$
2. Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \Omega$ such that $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ when $i≠j$ than
   $$ P(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty P(A_i)$$

And I need to know if $P^2$, $|P|$, and $P^{1\over2}$.
I think $P^2$ and $P^{1\over2}$ satisfy the conditions. But I don´t know how to prove $|P|$.

Comment: If $a+b=1$ that does not imply that $a^2+b^2=1$.  Similarly, $a+b=1$ does not imply that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=1$.  On the other hand, notice that $a+b=1$ *coupled with the knowledge* that $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$, you should notice that $|a|=a$ and $|b|=b$ so $|a|+|b|=a+b=1$.  Now, generalize or adapt these observations for explicit counterexamples or proofs for your problem.

Comment: This is what I thought. Suppose a partition of Ω A1UA2=Ω and A1∩A2=Ø. If you do (P^2)(A)+(P^2)(B)=1 (1). But then, if (1) is true, that doesn´t imply that P(A)^2+P(B)^2=1. So P^2 it is not a probability measure.